How to properly retrieve json data from URL in swift
I'm working on a project using mealDB, and this is my first time working with a json DB and none of the data is populating in my app. I have a function:
func fetchDesserts() async throws -> [Meal] {
        let urlString = "https://themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

        let mealResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(MealResponse.self, from: data)
        var meals: [Meal] = []

        for mealData in mealResponse.meals {
            guard let imageUrl = URL(string: mealData.strMealThumb) else {
                continue
            }

            let (imageData, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: imageUrl)
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                let meal = Meal(name: mealData.strMeal, image: image, id: Int(mealData.idMeal) ?? 0)
                meals.append(meal)
            }
        }

        return meals
    }

That I call here:
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = MealViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
            // Dessert Button
              NavigationLink(destination: {
                  DessertView(desserts: model.desserts)
                      .onAppear(perform: {
                          Task {
                              do {
                                  model.desserts = try await fetchDesserts()
                              } catch {
                                  print(error)
                              }
                          }
                      })
              }, label: {
                  ZStack {
                      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                          .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                      Text("Desserts")
                          .foregroundStyle(.white)
                  }
              })
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

I don't know if I improperly structured my query or am calling it incorrectly. On the mealDB website they state to use the API key "1" for development but I don't know where I would specify the API key. If someone can provide some feedback it would be much appreciated.
EDIT
I have updated the implementation of the task and modeled the query after workingDogs query from the attached repo yet I still receive the error nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C1] Connection has no local endpoint.
Here is my updated Code:
struct DessertView: View {
    // for procesing fetch request from json URL
    @State private var processing: Bool = false
    // desserts collectd
    @State private var desserts = [Meal]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if processing {
                ProgressView(label: {
                    Text("Loading Desserts...")
                })
            }
            else {
                // Standard View
            }
        }
        .task { // Query from mealsDB
            processing = true
            let response: ApiResponse? = await fetchMeals()
            processing = false
        }
    }
    
    // Fetch Meals Func
    func fetchMeals<T: Decodable>() async -> T? {
        // for testing
        
        // desserts
        let url = URL(string: "https://themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert")!
        
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                // throw URLError(.badServerResponse)   //  todo
                print(URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return nil
            }
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct Meal: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String?
    var imgURL: String? // String that represents a url of an image of the meal
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "idMeal"
        case name = "strMeal"
        case imgURL = "strMealThumb"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.imgURL = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imgURL)
    }
}

struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
    var meals: [Meal]?
}


The 1 key is the path component after v1. See the documentation which APIs support the key.

I don't get exactly what your question is. Are you getting an error? Because the link should work as you have it there. Also this wouldn't really be a iOS specific problem then, more a mealDB question.

Have a look at my github test code here: FreeMeal for how to
fetch the meals from themealdb API.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I updated my code and modeled it after your repo and am still receiving errors can you please provide some feedback?

You don't need that custominit(from decoder:...) as you are not using any custom structs which require custom logic. However you could make your imgURL as a URL type and then decode it correctly in your init, so you don't have to store a string.
But regarding your error: Could you add where are you running this code? iOS Simulator? Mac? And can you get curl running with the same URL and get a result?

your code works for me (with minor fix), see my answer. Let me know if that code does not work for you. If you get some errors, show the full error message.

Try this example code based on your original code and my fetchMeals, works well for me.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DessertView()
    }
}

struct DessertView: View {
    // for procesing fetch request from json URL
    @State private var processing: Bool = false
    // desserts collectd
    @State private var desserts = [Meal]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <--- here
            VStack {
                if processing {
                    ProgressView("Loading Desserts...")
                }
                else {
                    // --- here
                    List(desserts) { meal in
                        NavigationLink(meal.name ?? "", destination: DetailView(meal: meal))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // outside the NavigationStack
        .task { // Query from mealsDB
            processing = true
            let response: ApiResponse? = await fetchMeals()
            if let meals = response?.meals {
                desserts = meals   // <--- here
            }
            processing = false
        }
    }
    
    // Fetch Meals Func
    func fetchMeals<T: Decodable>() async -> T? {
        // desserts
        let url = URL(string: "https://themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert")!
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            // print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                // throw URLError(.badServerResponse)   //  todo
                print(URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return nil
            }
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("----> error: \(error)") // <--- important
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var meal: Meal
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 40) {
            if let imgurl = meal.imgURL {
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imgurl)) { image in
                    image.resizable()
                } placeholder: {
                    Image(systemName: "photo.circle.fill").resizable()
                }
                .frame(width: 333, height: 333)
                .padding(40)
            } else {
                Text("NO IMAGE THUMB").foregroundStyle(.blue)
            }
        }.padding(20)
    }
    
}

struct Meal: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String?
    var imgURL: String? // String that represents a url of an image of the meal
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "idMeal"
        case name = "strMeal"
        case imgURL = "strMealThumb"
    }
}

struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
    var meals: [Meal]?
}


In SwiftUI it's .task, not Task and it removes the need for the old @StateObject, so you can simply do:
struct DessertView: View {
    @Environment(\.mealsAPI) var mealsAPI
    @State var desserts: [Meal]?

    var body: some View {
        if let desserts {
            ForEach(desserts) {
                ...
            } 
        }
        else {
            Text("Loading...")
            .task {
                 do {
                     desserts = try await mealsAPI.fetchDesserts()
                 } catch {
                    print(error)
                 }
            }
        }
    }

Best to use Environment for your async funcs controller struct so it can be mocked in Previews.

for the \.mealsAPI param of the Enviroment var it's unable to determine the context of the key path. Do I replace that with the URL I want to query from? If can you provide some more context to your solution.

Sure here you go https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey

@StateObject isn't actually old. However from his previous code he used a view model so @StateObject is actually the correct choice rather than @State. If you just want to store the desserts you should use @State as you wrote. Also your snippet is missing the crucial information, that the environment needs to be passed from the parent view or a default needs to be set.

@Fabio this is SwiftUI the View structs are the view model.

@malhal his viewModel was named MealViewModel() so I thought he also had his fetchDesserts logic in there, but I looked at it again and it seems that's not the case. If you have a separate View Model to better separate your business logic from the view itself, you should use @StateObject. To make this clear: I didn't say that your way is wrong.

@Fabio it already is separate, we don't even have access to the view layer in SwiftUI it is is auto managed by the framework, ie based on the view model structs it creates/updates UIKit objects depending on the context and platform.

@StateObject is for when you need a reference type lifetime in a State, ie Combine pipeline or implementing a delegate.

@malhal I think we are misunderstanding each other but thats okay
